# Yii blog tutorial error: failed to open stream

Tags: php, yii, authentication

When i login occurs following problem.

```
PHP Error

Description

include(User.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Source File

D:\Badrakh\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\YiiBase.php(395)

00383:      * @return boolean whether the class has been loaded successfully
00384:      */
00385:     public static function autoload($className)
00386:     {
00387:         // use include so that the error PHP file may appear
00388:         if(isset(self::$_coreClasses[$className]))
00389:             include(YII_PATH.self::$_coreClasses[$className]);
00390:         else if(isset(self::$classMap[$className]))
00391:             include(self::$classMap[$className]);
00392:         else
00393:         {
00394:             if(strpos($className,'\\')===false)
00395:                 include($className.'.php');
00396:             else  // class name with namespace in PHP 5.3
```

Answer (score 0):

The file User.php doesn't exists. Are you sure it is the same dir? And is the include path set correct?

Some extra info will make it easier to awnser this question.

Comment: Sorry i am a begginer.How to set include path

Comment: As first try to set the full path of the file in the include function.

Comment: Tnx, I thing maybe should do this more framework way./Yii framework/

Comment: Solved it was tutorial mistake.